# How to handle possible exceptions that might occur when using GCP API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, error-handling

I am working on a python script to monitor resources in GCP.
I used the GCP Python API's and completed my script but I can't find how to add exception handling to it.
I did the same for AWS and I found the exceptions that occur in each method I used in AWS through the documentation since it provided all the possible exceptions that can occur in each API Method.
Is there a similar documentation I can refer to when it comes to GCP? I can't find similar explanation in GCP documentation.
For example in aws documentation:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_users

[list users method exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Fss.png)

I want similar reference in GCP like this.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Reference link for the exceptions raised by Google API core & clients:**
https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/exceptions.html

**Core Library for Google Client Libraries:**
Search this repository for sample code on exceptions.
https://github.com/googleapis/python-api-core

**Reference link for all api’s and their associated python client libraries:**
https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference
(For each service there is a link provided to the python client library. Clink on the link and search the repository for sample code on exceptions)

**Refer to the link below for more information on client libraries:**
https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries